# Will switching all subselects to temp tables and joins impact performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, temp-tables, subquery

One of our clients wants to introduce a new coding standard for their SQL stored procedures that dictates that all subselects will be replaced by temp tables and joins. They're citing readability as the reason for this change.

I don't really know a lot about the finer points of SQL performance tuning, but something about this makes me feel like it's going to cause performance issues. Am I right?

We are using MS SQL, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, it could cause performance issues.  In some cases, the use of temp table might improve performance, in some cases they might make performance worse.

Comment: Is there any hard and fast rule as to when they help and when they hurt?

Comment: Do they know about table variables? - they often out perform temp tables, depending on scale to a certain extent.

Comment: Consider this: Transforming all of the subselects into separate queries to populate temp tables and then replacing them in the final query is a mechanical transformation. You could (if you spent some time on it) write code that would take any query containing subselects and transform it so. So, if that transformation was **universally** beneficial, why haven't Microsoft implemented it themselves behind the scenes and saved you (and everyone else) the trouble?

Comment: @JonEgerton - It is more common for the reverse to be true though as the execution plans for queries involving `#temp` tables are often better.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Interesting, my experience of them has been that they usually give a decent boost when replacing # with @ tables. Other factors (don't want to get too chatty)

Comment: Table variables are faster with small sets of data in general and temp tables in larger sets, especially since you can index temp tables.

Comment: @JonEgerton - Yes [there can be a measurable difference in performance](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13392/3690) but really it works out at a couple of ms per execution. This will be drowned out unless you are dealing with a very small number of rows. Whereas the bad plans from lack of stats / accurate cardinality estimates can be catastrophically worse and lead to differences many orders of magtnitudes above that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm concerned that this question might be too broad and subject to interpretation.

In general, using temporary tables for intermediate results is bypassing SQL Server's query optimizer.  The creation of temporary tables incurs overhead, of creating the table and then reading the data back.  For instance, consider the following query that simply uses subqueries to define various column aliases:

```
select col3 + 1
from (select col2 * 2 as col3
      from (select col1/100 as col2
            from (select col*col as col1
                  from a
                 ) b
           ) c
     ) d
```

This structure for subqueries is rather common, because SQL does not allow the use of a column alias at the same level as its definition.  Materializing the intermediate tables would have a large impact on performance.

On the other hand, there are cases where a query might be structured as:

```
with cte as (
      <complex query here>
     )
select . . .
from cte cte1 join
     cte cte2
     on cte1.col = cte2.col;
```

In this case, the query engine actually runs the subquery for CTE twice.  Storing the results in a temporary table might improve performance.

My biggest objection to temporary tables is maintenance -- which is ironically why the client wants to use them.  For instance, changing the query might change the structure of the temporary tables.  In a single query, it is obvious which to keep and which to remove.  As a bunch of temporary tables, you run the risk of creating tables that are no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data and how the subselect is used orginally, it may increase performance or it may decrease performance. Correlated subqueries tend to perform poorly and temp tables or joins tend to improve performance in this case. Derived tables might be faster than temp table or might not depending on how many rows are being returned and if the temp table is indexed.  All would also depend on the design of your particular database and the rest of the query as well. And there are times when table variables or table-valued functions might be the best choice. You lose a lot of flexibility with this standard.

Personally I would explain to them what the possible issues would be and what other methods athere are for creating subselects. If they still want to do it then go with this new standard, but  ask permission to revise the standard to alow you to violate it if you need to performance tune the query. Also be sure to index the temp tables if they are going to contain a lot of records.